# Ruby on Rails: How do I run an automated rake task on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

In a Rails app running on Heroku, what is the best way to run an automated rake task that deletes records from database?
I would like to run a job that deletes all the posts that are older than a month, once per month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Heroku you could set up scheduler:

https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler

And then tell it to run a rake task. Something like this:

lib/tasks/your_task.rb

```
desc "describe your task"
task :clear_old_posts => [:environment] do
  posts = Post.where(created_at: <= Time.now - 1.month)
  posts.each do |post|
    post.destroy
  end
end
```

Then tell Heroku scheduler to run rake clear_old_posts every thirty days. Scheduler can be configured through the GUI, so no messing with crontab or anything.